# Javascript help, randomizing quiz questions

Tags: javascript, html

i made some code recently but im wondering how to make the quiz choose 3 questions out of 6 instead of displaying 6 straight away. Help would be appreciated. I want the quiz to choose 3 questions at random, then if its reloaded have a chance to choose another 3 questions, out of a total pool of 6.

```
<script language="JavaScript">


var numQues = 6;
var numChoi = 3;

var answers = new Array(6);
answers[0] = "16";
answers[1] = "8";
answers[2] = "The Walking Dead";
answers[3] = "Batman v Superman";
answers[4] = "Tupac";
answers[5] = "@ATAME2016";

function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;

  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";

  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

}


</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="quiz">
1. How many movie trailers are on the movie page?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="10">10<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="14">14<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="16">16<br>
<p>

2. How many pages are on this website?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="8">8<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="6">6<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="7">7<br>
<p>

3. What's the most popular show this week?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="The Walking Dead">The Walking Dead<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="Mandem on the wall">Mandem on the wall<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="Cotchin with Ksara">Cotchin with Ksara<br>
<p>

4. What movie has made the most money this week in the box office?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="Ride along 2">Ride along 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="Batman v Superman">Batman v Superman<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="GasMan">GasMan<br>
<p>

5. Which star in the celebrity page is no longer alive?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5" value="Tupac">Tupac<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5" value="50 Cent">50 Cent<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5" value="Bradley cooper">Bradley cooper<br>
<p>

6. What is our twitter account name (@)?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q6" value="@ATAME">@ATAME<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q6" value="@ATAME2016">@ATAME2016<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q6" value="@A2THETAME">@A2THETAME<br>
<p>

<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear"><p>
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>




</div>
```

Comment: Close your `<p>` with `</p>`: ex. `<p>text of paragraph</p>`

Comment: Good point @zer00ne. I just found this on W3's site: "A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element." https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element However the `<p>` tags above are followed by text. Good tip!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `Math.random()` function. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

A common example is found at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

I'd try something like this, using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
// Hides all questions on page load.
$('.questions').hide();

// Randomly shows 3 questions.
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var questionId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    $('#question-' + questionId).show();
}
```

Then wrap your questions in wrapping `<div>` or `<p>` tags like this:

```
<div id="question-1" class="questions">
    1. How many movie trailers are on the movie page?<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="10">10<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="14">14<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="16">16<br>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<p id="question-1" class="questions">
    1. How many movie trailers are on the movie page?<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="10">10<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="14">14<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="question1" value="16">16<br>
</p>
```